# Random numbers causing problems

Tags: c++

Say I have a member variable `vector<bool> rightWall;`. rightWall has `width*height` indices. I want to access a random index of rightWall. So I do:

```
index1=rand()%(width*height-1);
rightWall[index1]=true;
```

But I get Valgrind errors: Invalid read of size 8. rightWall was never initialized or anything, and I'm not sure it's really supposed to, since its only bools. What can be the problem?

Comment: Have you stepped through with a debugger?  What are the actual values that `index1` and `index2` are being set to?  Are they all within range of `rightWall`?

Comment: Can you post a complete, compilable program that demonstrates the problem?  It shouldn't take more than 20 lines of code based on your description.

Comment: Are you sure that `rightWall` has `width*height` elements? You didn't just `reserve` space for that many? And you didn't do anything with `index2`. A proper testcase will sort this out in mere moments.

Comment: What line are you getting the warning for? there is no read operation in the lines you quote. Also, you're not using `index2` in this code.

Comment: That's pretty much the only code that has anything to do with rightWall. I've omitted some conditionals which really shouldnt matter.

Comment: @Tomalak was I supposed to reserve space for that many?

Comment: @bitmoe, except, you know, the declaration..

Comment: Along with Tomalak, are you doing rightWall.resize(width*height) ?  When you say rightWall has width*height indices how do you know?  Seems like it doesn't.

Comment: @Guy I thought vectors were dynamic? Or is that only when I use push_back? And no I didnt do resize. But I think that might have been the problem..

Comment: @bitmoe they are dynamic but only if you tell them to change size with `resize` or `push_back`, `push_front`

Comment: @bitmoe: only when you use push_back or other methods.  You can't index them dynamically.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get a vector of a certain size you need to initialize it like so:

```
vector<bool> rightWall(width*height);
```

or resize it:

```
vector<bool> rightWall;
rightWall.resize(width*height);
```